# How to do a bulk insert while avoiding duplicates in Postgresql

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm working in nodejs, hosted at Heroku (free plan so far).

I get the data from elsewhere automatically (this part work fine and I get JSON or CVS), and my goal is do add them into a Prostresql DB.

While, I'm new to DB mangement and Postgresql, I've made my research before posting this. I'm aware that the [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command exist, and how to [INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) multiple data without duplicate. But my problem is a mix of both (plus another difficulty).

I hope my question is not breaking the rules.

---

**Short version**, I need to :

- Add lots of data a once
- Never create duplicate
- Rename column name between source data and my table

---

**Long version** with details :

The data I collect are from multiples sources (2 for now but will get bigger) and are quite big (>1000).

I also need to remap the column name to one unified system. What could be called "firstDay" on one source is called "dateBegin" in another, and I want them to be called "startDate" in my table.

If I'm using INSERT, I take care of this myself (in JS) while constructing the query. But maybe COPY could do that in a better way. Also, INSERT seem to have a limit of data you can push in one time, and so I will need to divide my query multiple time and maybe use callback or promise to avoid drowning the DB.

And finally, I will update this DB regularly and automatically and they will be a lot of duplicate. Hopefully, every piece of data has an unique id, and I have made a column PRIMARY KEY in the table that store this id. I thought it may eliminate any problem with duplicate, but I may be wrong.

My first version was very ugly (for loop making a new query a every loop) and didn't work. I was thinking about doing 1000 data at a time in a recursive way waiting for callback before sending another batch. It seem clunky and time expensive to do it that way. COPY seem perfect if I can select/rename/remap columns and avoid duplicated. I've read the documentation and I don't see a way to do that.

---

Thank you very much, any help is welcome. I'm still learning so please be kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this before using temporary tables to "stage" your data and then do an INSERT SELECT to move the data from staging to your production table.

For populating your staging table you can use bulk INSERTs or COPY.

For example,

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE staging_my_table ( // your columns etc );

// Now that you have your staging table you can bulk INSERT or COPY
// into it from your code, e.g.,
INSERT INTO staging_my_table (blah, bloo, firstDay) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), etc.

// Now you can do an INSERT into your live table from your staging, e.g.,
INSERT INTO my_table (blah, bloo, startDate)
SELECT cool, bloo, firstDay
FROM staging_my_table staging
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mytable
    WHERE staging.bloo = mytable.bloo
);

COMMIT;
```

There are always exceptions, but this might just work for you.

Have a good one

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, if I understand, SELECT is used to remap/rename column ?
I will implement your solution very soon. Thanks again.

Comment: You could use the SELECT to remap/rename a column yes.  The only problem is your code would have to make a different staging table for each variation.  Another option would be to keep the staging table exactly as your live table and instead do the remapping of the column names before you INSERT into the staging, e.g., INSERT INTO staging_my_table (blah, bloo, startDate) VALUES ($blah, $bloo, $firstDay).  Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I've use the second option as it is easier. I just needed to add `DISCARD TEMP;` since I do this multiple times (multiple sources). I also used a npm module to escape text properly. 

Now, everything work perfectly and I've learn a lot about PostgreSQL.

Thank you again for your help !